# Parse String containing a Number into a INT

Tags: java, string, parsing, integer

I got a String that contains the Number 0.
Know, i need to parse it into a `int` so i tried the following:

```
int oldfollowcounter = Integer.parseInt(followerzahl);
```

`followerzahl` is the String.

I always get that Error:

```
Exception in thread "Timer-4" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0
"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at YBot.MyBot$3.run(MyBot.java:472)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

and the local `int` is just empty.

Any Ideas?

String contains:

```
followerzahl=0

followerzahl=0

followerzahl=0

followerzahl=0
```

Comment: Looks like there is a line break after the zero. Try to call `String#trim()`

Comment: show us your full string

Comment: this is the full string: "0\n"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Integer.parseInt` is a very strict parser, it will not parse a `String` unless it contains only a valid integer and nothing else.

You need to remove anything else that might be in the String first. In this case it looks like there is whitespace (a linefeed) after the number so `followerzahl.trim()` would be enough to remove the whitespace. If there is more (such as quote marks or other characters) you will need to write something to extract just the bit of the String containing the number and then parse that.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the **" 0"** or **"0."**.

Well lets look at it `Integer.parseInt` only allows **digits** so the **decimal point**, additional **spaces** are illegal.

hence the **NumberFormatException**

You should make sure that your input really is an

**integer** (i.e. "20")

or if you actually want to allow decimals then use

`Double.parseDouble` or `Float.parseFloat`,

or if any space " 0" is found you should use first

`Integer.parseInt(followerzahl.trim())`,

or `Double.parseInt(followerzahl.trim())` and  that should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
int oldfollowcounter = Integer.parseInt(followerzahl);
```

The `followerzahl` string must be integer number.

Use below code :

```
        String followerzahl = "0";
        int oldfollowcounter = Integer.parseInt(followerzahl);
        System.out.println(oldfollowcounter);
```

Comment: "0 is not integer number @exception

Comment: The second `"` is on another line, it ain't `"0`

Comment: This means what exactly? I dont get it :3

Comment: The `"` comes from the error message, it is not part of the string value.

Comment: String followerzahl = "0"; Its valid,you can cast to integer

Comment: @user3220962 have u declare string like this.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have `"0` inside your string `followerzahl`. Please recheck !

Comment: the string which was tried to parse is always represent with qoutes in the exception... the problem is the line serperator.

Comment: added the full text of the string above. it looks liek i got an "enter" in it

Answer (score 0):

It is important to make sure that your string does not contain any other characters except numbers when you are parsing it. Most likely your string contains a blank space, a punctuation mark or something that does not translate into an integer. So it is always advised to check your string before parsing it.

In this scenario it is most likely to be a **"** in the string in the wrong place.